# Can't find columns after declaration in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a problem. I am creating a trigger which will prompt the user to not create a purchase order with a higher cost to their selling cost. I have declared a column on my script but its still showing this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure _trgZSCheckPrice, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Invalid column name 'fExclPrice'

The two columns are `@Check` and `@Excl`

I have attached my code below any help is advisable:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER _trgZSCheckPrice
ON [dbo].[_btblInvoiceLines] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
        @Valid int,
        @ValidPO int,
        @DocType int,
        @DocState int,
        @Check int,
        @Excl float,
        @POPrice float

    SELECT
        @Check = ubIICheck,
        @Excl = fExclPrice,
        @POPrice = fUnitPriceExcl
    FROM 
        INSERTED

    SELECT 
        @Excl = fExclPrice,
        @Check = ubIICheck 
    FROM 
        stkitem A 
    INNER JOIN 
        _etblPriceListPrices B ON A.StockLink = B.iStockID  

    SELECT 
        @POPrice = fUnitPriceExcl 
    FROM 
        _btblInvoiceLines C 
    LEFT JOIN 
        InvNum D ON C.iInvoiceID = D.AutoIndex 
BEGIN
    IF (@DocType = 5 AND @DocState <> 7) AND @CHECK = 1
    BEGIN
        IF @Excl > @POPrice
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Message from Management: 
You are not allowed to Purchase above Selling Cost.
The transaction will be rolled back. ', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    END
END 
END
```

Comment: So many things wrong it's difficult to know where to start. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *mutliple* rows and you're ignoring those rows. Then you perform two additional queries that *aren't correlated* with the information you *did* pull from `inserted`. And then there's storing money in `float`s. None of these relate to your current problem but since we don't have your table definitions, it's impossible to help out on that really. Just be aware that these other problems exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ideally, here, you'd be implementing this as a multi-table `CHECK` constraint (in fact, in standard SQL, these are called `ASSERTION`s. So far as I'm aware, only Postgre implements them).

If you're happy to trade away the ability to completely control the error message, I'd usually prefer to implement this in a *declarative* manner rather than relying on a trigger.

Here's how to do such a check with an indexed view. First a couple of tables that are somewhat like your problem domain (but not very fleshed out since you didn't put any definitions in your question):

```
create table dbo.ListPrices (
    ID int not null,
    Price decimal(12,4) not null,
    constraint PK_ListPrices PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
create table dbo.Orders (
    ID int not null,
    ListPriceID int not null,
    MyPrice decimal(12,4) not null,
    constraint PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint FK_Orders_ListPrices FOREIGN KEY (ListPriceID)
         references dbo.ListPrices (ID)
)
go
insert into dbo.ListPrices (ID,Price) values (1,12.50),(2,25.00)
```

And now we create a special helper table. It's not needed if you already have a suitable table (such as a numbers table) in your database:

```
create table dbo.Two (
    n int not null,
    constraint PK_Two PRIMARY KEY (n),
    constraint CK_Two_Only CHECK (n in (1,2))
)
go
insert into dbo.Two (n) values (1),(2)
```

And now we create the view:

```
go
create view dbo.DRI_NoOrderPricesOverListPrices
with schemabinding
as
    select
        1 as p /* Constant */
    from
        dbo.Two t
            cross join
        dbo.Orders o
            inner join
        dbo.ListPrices lp
            on
                o.ListPriceID = lp.ID
    where
        /*Conditions for failure*/
        o.MyPrice > lp.Price
go
create unique clustered index IX_NoOrderPricesOverListPrices
    on DRI_NoOrderPricesOverListPrices(p)
```

The key feature here is that the view joins all of the tables we're interested in together and we can put whatever conditions we like in the `where` clause, referencing multiple tables, comparing column values, etc.

The conditions we're specifying is for what *shouldn't* be allowed in the database. So, we're saying we should be able to insert a row in `Orders` provided that its price is less than or equal to the price in line items.

And we can. This insert succeeds:

```
insert into Orders (ID,ListPriceID,MyPrice) values (1,2,17.00)
```

And this one fails:

```
insert into Orders (ID,ListPriceID,MyPrice) values (2,1,17.00)
```

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 42
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.DRI_NoOrderPricesOverListPrices' with unique index 'IX_NoOrderPricesOverListPrices'. The duplicate key value is (1).

(As I said at the top, we don't get so much control over the error message - but making a good choice of name here should make it reasonable to deduce what's happening and directly exposing SQL Server error messages to the users is something I'd generally try to avoid)